# IIS7 How to redirect file with extention dll

Tags: iis-7

I have a legacy application that I am now replacing with .Net.

Requests to that legacy application look like this:
h ttp://www.mywebsite.com/scripts/mgrqispi.dll?appname=app&prgname=prg&....

I would like to set the iis in a way that will automatically redirect them to the following url:
h ttp://www.mywebsite.com/myAspPage.aspx?appname=app&prgname=prg&....

Note that it's important for me to keep the url parameters.

Also note, that I don't care if it's redirect to the client - or if I can just tell the iis to redirect the request itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you are managing the redirection on the server not on the clients. (Different Browsers and the like will make this a pretty error-prone job)

Adressing the problem like I would do it with apache I'll think of some URL Rewriting. ISAPI_Rewrite (http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) might be what you are looking for.

An example (untested):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/scripts/mgrispi.dll(.+)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/myAspPage.aspx$1 [NC]
```